# How to derive volumetric flow rate?

Tags: chemical-engineering

Given the mass flow rate in lbs/min, the specific gravity of a substance, the temperature in F, and the density in lbs/ft^3, what is the equation to derive the volumetric flow in Gallons/Min?

Comment: - Specific gravity with respect to what?
- Why would you need specific gravity and temperature?
- You know how many "lbs/min", you know how many "lbs/ft^3", thus you can find out how many "ft^3/min" (volumetric flow). And if you know find out how many "Gallons/ft^3" you can find "gallons/min"
- Offer more detail to your scenario, this will lead to better answers.

Comment: @Andrew Specific gravity is typically in relation to water unless otherwise stated.

Comment: Why would you need temperature? Why do you need specific gravity and density?  Specific gravity is a measure of density.  This is odd.  All you need to convert is from ft^3 to gallon that is an easy google.

Comment: I dont know the gal/ft^3.The specific gravity is something other than water. Its actually oil at 0.703.   How does temperature affect the equation? I guess its wrapped up in the density. Plus its 'Merica were talking about here therefore its all about the gallons per minute.

Answer (score 1):

v lbs / min * w ft^3 / lbs * x gal / ft^3 = z gal / min

Comment: Wouldn't you multiply (x gal / ft^3) to the other terms of the equations instead of adding it?

Comment: This answer could be improved with some text, by stating the mass flow rate is divided by the density, instead of having to imply it from the equation.

Comment: The gal/ft^3 is not available otherwise the equation is simple.

Comment: @ForgottenKahz Really, the volume of a gallon is not available?

Comment: opps! Now that I think about it. The volume of a gallon is availible.

Comment: @ForgottenKahz And I don't see an up vote.

Answer (score 0):

Go metric, man. Go metric.

$$ v = \rho m $$

where $ v $ is volume (litre), $ \rho $ is the density and $ m $ is the mass (kg).

For a given time, $ t $ the formula could be re-written as $ \frac {v}{t} = \rho \frac {m}{t} $ but the 't' terms cancel out and the numerical answer is the same.